# Reusing last frame until new one arrives

Tags: ffmpeg

Using ffmpeg to take stream from stdin (received over the network) and sending it to Decklink output. There might be issues with the network where video frames stop coming for a bit but audio continues, yet if decklink doesn't receive new video frames it doesnt play the audio either. So I want ffmpeg to keep sending the last frame available to output until new frame arrives.

Comment: did find any solution to it I am also facing same issue